# Apache 2.4 Fails to install on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, apache2.4

```
Windows 10
Apache 2.4-64 (httpd-2.4.27-Win64-VC15.zip)
```

I downloaded httpd-2.4.27-Win64-VC15.zip and unpacked it to c:Apache24

I modified the httpd.conf file:

```
Listen *:80
ServerName localhost:80

cd \Apache24\bin

httpd -k shutdown
```

response is:

```
The 'Apache2.4' service is not started

httpd -k install
```

response is:

```
[Wed Aug 23 13:17:03.258023 2017] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 1196:tid 412] AH00433: Apache2.4: Service is already installed.
```

At one point, Apache 2.4 was installed to a directory called c:\localhost and may have been improperly removed.

I checked the services/processes, and killed the IIS server and there is no mention of an Apache 2.4 running. I also checked the startup folder, and there is no Apache 2.4

It seems that Apache 2.4, or some other ghost process, that thinks Apache 2.4 is still running in the non-existing c:\localhost folder. I've rebooted the system, to no avail. Any idea how to diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In **CMD**

```
cd \apache24\bin

httpd -k uninstall       

httpd -k install
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

1. Go to C:\Apache24\conf and open httpd.conf in notepad
2. Search for 'Listen 80'
3. Change port number to 85 i.e. 'Listen 85' or whatever you prefer

Answer (score 0):

Try this in **CMD**

```
C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

1. You must uninstall Apache:

`sc delete "[name service]"`

`sc delete "Apache2.4"`

2. Restart pc
3. `cmd how administrator`
4. `cd \apache24\bin`
5. `httpd -k install`